# A phrase meaning over-optimizing very small chunks

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a phrase that means trying to optimize the smaller chunk of something? I've seen such a phrase, used in derogative manner.

Here is the context:

> Alice: I've spent the whole day browsing social media. Now I have 2
> hours to prepare for the Calculus exam tomorrow. Quick, I need some
> productivity tips.
>
> Bob: You are *cutting a thin string into
> thinner*?

Is there such a phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't fit the context perfectly, but there's a phrase

> You can't see the forest for the trees.

In this phrase, "for the trees" means "because of the trees", so it means that focus on little parts of something obscures the view of the whole.

[Cambridge can't see the forest for the trees](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/can-t-see-the-forest-for-the-trees)

> to be unable to understand a situation clearly because you are too involved in it

In your extreme example, though, you might want to say "Forget the trees, the forest is on fire!". Or, "Have you checked the availability of Calculus next semester?"